How to correctly pass a list of async callbacks and run them on another thread
Consider the below code example. I would like to have a Scheduler that registers a list of async callbacks. The async callbacks get executed on a separate thread that gets kicked off when the Scheduler is ran.
How can this be built in rust? I am having issues with either passing my async callbacks OR sharing them accross the newly spawned thread.
use std::{future::Future, sync::Arc};

use tokio::sync::Mutex;

struct SchedulerState {
    callbacks: Vec<Box<dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>,
}

struct Scheduler {
    state: Arc<Mutex<SchedulerState>>,
}

impl Scheduler {
    async fn add_callback(&mut self, callback: Box<dyn Fn() -> Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>) {
        let state = self.state.clone();
        let mut state = state.lock().await;
        state.callbacks.push(callback);
    }

    async fn run(&mut self) {
        // handle whether running or not

        let shared = Arc::clone(&self.state);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            for callback in shared.lock().await.callbacks {
                callback.await;
            }
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    let scheduler = Scheduler {
        state: Arc::new(Mutex::new(SchedulerState { callbacks: vec![] })),
    };

    scheduler.add_callback(Box::new(async move || {
        let test = 0;
    }));
}


I noticed Scheduler::run is async but doesn't need to be. Would you prefer if it awaited the scheduled callbacks? Or could it be changed to a synchronous function?

yes, actual good catch, I want to await there the async callbacks, edited the op

That's an improvement but, due to tokio::spawn, Scheduler::run still doesn't need to be async. If you want it to be async anyway, call it in main with .await. Otherwise, please remove async and call it without .await. Seeing Scheduler::run get called may increase the chance of a useful answer.

Also, could you clarify why your future isn't Sync? Does it contain a type that isn't Sync and, if so, what? Or do you mean Rust complains that it isn't Sync?
